# Need top 10 connected nodes to use in a cypher sub query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find out the 10 most connected nodes in my graph and use those for a sub query

```
START ico=node:Index(type="XYZ")
MATCH ico<-[:references]-n<-[:contains]-m
WITH distinct ico, n, m
```

How do i only process those ico which are referred the most ( I need top ten most referred nodes).

Any help in this matter is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a distinct. Since I don't know what your subquery will look like, you can get started with the following:

```
START ico=node:Index(type="XYZ")
MATCH ico<-[:references]-n
WITH ico, length(collect(n)) as refs
ORDER BY refs DESC
LIMIT 10
MATCH ico ... your sub query here...
```